# validation on focusout and click event

Tags: javascript, validation

i m working with some validation on focus out event now i want to check all these validation on button click event how can i do that

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").focusout(function () {
    var Password = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").val();
    if (Password == '') {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").css('border-color', 'red');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_spPassword").css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
    else if (Password.length < 8) {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").css('border-color', 'red');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_spPassword").css('visibility', 'visible');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_spPassword").text("Password should be atleast 8 characters ")
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").css('border-color', '');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_spPassword").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: remember that i have multiple fields

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#yourbuttonid').on("click" , function() {
  //your existing above logic comes here
});
```

Comment: if i use this then all focusout event will not work on focus out
i tried this

Comment: $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").on("focusout" , function(){
      //your logic
    });

Make sure that the jquery is able to find your element and you have loaded jquery.
Also make sure that you are writing your script after you have rendered html. This method guarantees that jquery can findyour element via the id that you are supplying. If possible share your html code too.

Comment: Also i suggest that use any one event for validation. On click is preferable.
Because when you click on the button the focus out event will fire anyway. So no need to keep both the events.

Comment: @GauravShah That comment should be part of your answer. Use the edit function next time to add relevant information to your own answers.

Answer (score 0):

Repeated code is ought to be a `function`, so define this `validation` `function`:

```
function validation() {
    var Password = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").val();
    if (Password == '') {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").css('border-color', 'red');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_spPassword").css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
    else if (Password.length < 8) {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").css('border-color', 'red');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_spPassword").css('visibility', 'visible');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_spPassword").text("Password should be atleast 8 characters ")
    }
    else {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").css('border-color', '');
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_spPassword").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

Then, you call this `function` on your events:

```
$("#ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPassword").focusout(function () {
    validation();
});

$("#myButton").click(function() {
    validation();
});
```